# Derivatives of summation and index shifting (intuition)

Tags: calculus, economics

I'm Working on an econ otimization problem (it's part of a model on david romer's advanced macro book. chapter 7, page 318). And my calc/algebra background is weak.

The optimization s as follows:

Min $\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_t(p_i - p_t^*)^2 $ , w.r.t  $p_i$

What I would normally do is:

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty 2q_t(p_i - p_t^*)1 =0 $$

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty 2q_t p_i =\sum_{t=0}^\infty 2q_t(p_t^*) $$

$$2p_i\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_t =2\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_tp_t^* $$

$$p_i=\frac{\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_tp_t^*}{\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_t}$$

The correct step, on the book, is :
$$p_i=\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{q_t}{\sum_{\tau=0}^\infty q_{\tau}} p_t^* $$

So:

1. Where does $ \sum_{\tau=0}^\infty q_{\tau} $ term comes from, and how does it end up inside the summation?
2. Isn't $ \sum_{\tau=0}^\infty q_{\tau} = \sum_{t=0}^\infty q_t$, as both go from zero to infinity ?  What is the most intuitive form of understanding why this happens?
3. This could be a bit broad: I've only studied calculus 1 a few years ago. What kind of material covers these specific kinds of derivatives applied on summation and integrals ?

Thanks and sorry in advance for the math typing/english. First time using mathjax and stackexchange :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is the same as the book but they are using two different summation indexes to avoid confusing them.

If the book had written it like this:

$p_i=\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{ q_t}{\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_t}p_t^*$

then this could be read as

$p_i= \frac{ q_0}{\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_0}p_0^* + \frac{ q_1}{\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_1}p_1^* + \sum_{t=2}^\infty \frac{ q_t}{\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_t}p_t^*$

Comment: Thanks, Hugh! So the index change is just really to avoid confusion. 

By inserting the $\sum_{t=0}^\infty q_t$ inside the summation (your first line), and exchanging the indices (from t to tau), I'm basically treating it as a constant (in relation to the outside summation, that is indexed on i) ? Is this an ok form of understanding the manipulation?

And can I leave them both indexed to "i" or it is formally deemed as a wrong way of writing ?

Thanks!